# How Can I Pagination Next and Previous With Firebase Database Without createdAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is no createdAt column in the database.

I'm trying to pagination, but it's not working properly.

When I press the previous button endBefore(firstElement)
When I press the next button startAfter(lastElement)

There is no problem going forward, but the page order is broken when coming back.

How can I solve this?

```
const queryConstraints = []
if(onlyMain) queryConstraints.push(where("mainpost","==",true))
if(postType === "previous") queryConstraints.push(endBefore(visibleObject))
if(postType === "next") queryConstraints.push(startAfter(visibleObject))


 query(collection(db,"posts"),orderBy("title"),where("title", ">=", "Demo"),limit(count),...queryConstraints)
```

Comment: Can you explain "broken"? Are you sure no new documents are added in "posts" or title is updated that'll change the order of documents? Also can you please share you component as well just to ensure you are mapping the docs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're browsing backwards, you need to [use `limitToLast`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#limittolast) instead of `limit`. With `limitToLast` the query returns the documents *before* the cursor object that you specify, while using `limit` returns the ones *after* it.